# Child div onclick event: onclick on dynamically added children divs doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div to which I add children divs in a loop. For each child I try to add an `onclick` event - so that the child div would change its color when clicked on:

```
    var div;
    for (var i=1; i<=size*size; i++)  {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = i;
        div.style.width = 480/size + "px";
        div.style.height = 480/size + "px";

        div.onclick= function()  {
            div.style.backgroundColor="orange";
        }
        resultNode.appendChild(div);
    }
```

However only the last div changes its color, no matter what child is clicked on. I suspect its because `var div`'s last value is the last child, but shouldn't the `onclick` added to its previous objects remain with those objects once they are added inside `resultNode`?

[image]

I also tried adding this loop:

```
    var children=resultNode.children;
    for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++)  {
        children.item(i).onclick = function()  {
            children.item(i).style.backgroundColor="blue";
            alert(i);
        }
    }
```

However, it only works for a single child which index varies, depending of the amount of children. If there are only `25` (its the value of `size*size` in the code) children, the child with index `6` would get colored. If there are `100` children, the `11`th child would get colored, if there are `400` children, `21`th child would get colored. That is always the second div of the second row (there are `size*size` divs which form a square with `size` rows and `size` columns, meaning the div that gets colored is in the `size`+1 position):

[image]

I don't understand this behavior. Why does this happen and how should I edit the code to achieve the desired result (any child div when clicked on changes its color)?

Comment: The reason why the snippets are not working is explained [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` does not reference what you are expecting within the `click` handler, see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). You can use `event.target` to reference the element where the event was dispatched

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = i;
  div.textContent = i;
  div.onclick = e => e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  resultNode.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="resultNode"></div>
```

Alternatively

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  ((div) => {
    div.id = i;
    div.textContent = i;
    div.onclick = e => div.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    resultNode.appendChild(div);
  })(div)
}
```

```html
<div id="resultNode"></div>
```

Comment: Note, due to using `let` `div` will be the same `div` in first example within `onclick` handler.

Comment: Thank you. Coming from Java, Javascript is hard. Storing functions in array, primitives like `i` being seemingly passed be reference instead of by value. Mind-blowing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would also work if you just tweak it as below:

```
var div;
    for (var i=1; i<=size*size; i++)  {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = i;
        div.style.width = 480/size + "px";
        div.style.height = 480/size + "px";

        div.onclick= function()  {
            this.style.backgroundColor="orange";
        }
        resultNode.appendChild(div);
    }
```

Inside onclick function just change it to `this.style.background = 'orange'` instead of `div.style.background = 'orange'` object. Your code was not working because div object is pointing to your last div.